# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error reading in csv with d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to test a web app I'm building using d3.js. This involves reading in a CSV file from my network drive, on my local machine.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text" src="./data/TimelineData.csv"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>


(function(){

d3.csv("http://data/TimelineData.csv")
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
})
.catch(function(error){

})
})();
```

But, there seems to be an issue accessing the csv:

```
d3.min.js:2 GET http://data/TimelineData.csv net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I thought this error was due to trying to open a local file on the web, but this error persists even when testing the site on a server (prepros).  How can I solve this?

Comment: don't use `./` in url.

Comment: You don't use `http:` for network drives you would use `file:///` scheme like a local file (though that still wont get you access as it would be blocked for security). You would use http(s) if you were running a server program from your networked computer and had `data` in your `hosts` file setup to point to your networked computer's ip

Comment: Patrick Evans - so what should I do in this case?

Comment: Use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications) to read a file provided through a file input `<input type="file">` or drag and drop operation. Or setup a server (apache, nodejs, etc) on the networked computer to serve the files you want.

Comment: Hmm, thanks,  I've followed your suggestion and read the API but this still gives the same error:  <script type="file" src="/data/TimelineData.csv"

Comment: Oh, wait it's working. Using type = "file" in combination with  d3.csv("data/TimelineData.csv") solved the issue.